define generic for pair of property name and value formatter for that property
Let's assume there is a object definition:
type Obj = {
    i: number
    b: boolean
    s: string
}

I want to define a type which would allow me to pass property name and a callback which would expect single argument with exactly the same type as a property:
const a: FormatEntry = {
    accessor: 'b',
    formatter: (value: boolean) => value ? 'a' : 'b'
}

My best try to far
type FormatEntry<K extends keyof Obj> = {
    accessor: K,
    formatter: (value: Obj[K]) => string
}

But it gives me an error "Generic type 'FormatEntry' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)" which I don't understand - I would expect TS to infer the generic's argument on its own
Sure, I can provide that argument:
const a: FormatEntry<'b'> = {
    accessor: 'b',
    formatter: (value: boolean) => value ? 'a' : 'b'
}

but it's double work. What am I doing wrong?

TS doesn't infer generic type arguments for generic types, only when you call generic functions. There's a feature request at ms/TS#32794 for that but it's not in the language. Instead of a generic you probably just want a union type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

thank you @jcalz. yes, your solution absolutely addresses the question. I'd never think about generating union with mapping type, it's so cool!

Unfortunately TypeScript will not infer type arguments for generic types like your FormatEntry. It will only infer type arguments when you call generic functions. This is essentially a missing feature, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#32794. If that were to be implemented, maybe you could write
// NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT, DO NOT TRY THIS
type FormatEntry<K extends keyof Obj = infer> = {
    accessor: K,
    formatter: (value: Obj[K]) => string
}
const s: FormatEntry = { accessor: 's', formatter: s => s.toUpperCase() }
//    ^? const s: FormatEntry<"s">

where the K type parameter has a default of the hypothetical infer type, and so assigning a value to a variable of type FormatEntry would make TypeScript infer the argument, as shown above. Until and unless that feature is implemented, though, you'll need to work around it.

One general approach is to use a generic helper function, which behaves similarly to your desired type:
const formatEntry = <K extends keyof Obj>(f: FormatEntry<K>) => f;

Then instead of writing const s: FormatEntry = {⋯}, you write const s = formatEntry({⋯}):
const s = formatEntry({ accessor: 's', formatter: s => s.toUpperCase() });
//    ^? const s: FormatEntry<"s">

And now you get the desired inference. TypeScript infers K as "s" from the argument to formatEntry(), and since the function just returns its input, the type of s is FormatEntry<"s">.

But for the example as written, you might not actually need FormatEntry to be generic at all. It seems that conceptually a FormatEntry would be a union of the three possible generic versions. That is, you want a type equivalent to FormatEntry<"i"> | FormatEntry<"b"> | FormatEntry<"s">:
type FormatEntry = {
    accessor: "i";
    formatter: (value: number) => string;
} | {
    accessor: "b";
    formatter: (value: boolean) => string;
} | {
    accessor: "s";
    formatter: (value: string) => string;
}

That's a discriminated union where accessor is the discriminant property:
let a: FormatEntry;
a = { accessor: 'b', formatter: value => value ? 'a' : 'b' };
a = { accessor: 's', formatter: s => s.toUpperCase() };
a = { accessor: 'i', formatter: i => i.toFixed(2) };

Since a is of a union type you can reassign it to any member of the union (as opposed to something that is inferred to be just one member forever), and since it's a discriminated union, TS will infer the parameter type of formatter from the value of the accessor property.
The only problem with the above type is that it's been written out manually. We can fix that by making TypeScript compute the desired type in terms of Obj, like this:
type FormatEntry = { [K in keyof Obj]: {
    accessor: K,
    formatter: (value: Obj[K]) => string
} }[keyof Obj];

That's called a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. The idea is that we make a mapped type and then immediately index into it with the full set of keys, resulting in a union. In general, if you have a generic type F<P> where P is a keylike type, and you want to compute the union of F<P> for every P in some union K, then you can write {[P in K]: F<P>}[K].
So FormatEntry is now a discriminated union computed as a distribute object type over your original definition for FormatEntry<K> for every K in keyof Obj, and is equivalent to the manually-written-out version above.
Playground link to code

what a level of details! thank you!
